# Translate Perl Script to T-SQL

Tags: sql, perl, t-sql, ssis

Ok - I need help from a Perl Guru on this one. A co-worker provided me code from a Perl application they support and how it encodes values before it writes the data to Oracle. Don't ask me why they did this encoding (appears to be for special characters). The values are being written to a CLOB in Oracle. I need an equivalent decode for use in an SSIS package in SQL Server.

Basically I am reading the data from the Oracle database using an SSIS package and need to decode the values. The "+" sign between words is easy with a replace statement (not sure that is the best way, but seems to work so far).

This one is beyond my skill set, because my Perl script skills are limited (yes I have done some reading, but not turning out to be as easy as I thought since I don't know Perl very well). I am only interested in decoding the string not encoding.

BTW as a hint to this, I know that %29 equals a ")" sign. Looks to be using regex, but I am not well versed in using that either (I know I need to learn it).

```
sub decodeValue($)
    {
        my $varRef = shift;

        ${$varRef} =~  tr/+/ /;
        ${$varRef} =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9]{2})/pack("C",hex($1))/eg;
        ${$varRef} =~ tr/\cM//;
        ${$varRef} =~ s/"/\&#34;/g;
        return;
    }


sub encodeValue($)
    {
        my $varRef = shift;

        # ${$varRef} =~  tr/ /+/;
        ${$varRef} =~  s/"/\&#34;/g;
        ${$varRef} =~  s/'/\&#39;/g;
        ${$varRef} =~  s/(\W)/sprintf( "%%%x", ord($1) )/eg;
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Too much info, Boil this down to small sample input, required output from that same input, current code, current output/error msgs and minimal comments about where you are confused. Good luck.

Comment: Please note the tags at the bottom of your post. You set them when you create the question (and the site "guesses" and includes irrelevant ones if you don't take the time to look). You have "oracle" which I will go ahead and delete, but that is your job when you post a question!

Answer (score 2):

The `encodeValue` subroutine is a simple URL-encoding algorithm, with additional steps to convert single and double quotes to their equivalent HTML entities. You need to write Transact-SQL code to decode those steps in reverse order, so the first thing that must be done is to replace all `%7f`-type sequences with their equivalent characters

You should look at [*URL Decode in T-SQL*](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1005508/URL-Decode-in-T-SQL) for code to do that. It supports the full UTF-8 character set. You could remove all the `ELSE IF @Byte1Value` blocks to support only 7-bit ASCII if you wish, but it will work fine for you as it stands

The remaining conversions of single and double-quotes and spaces can be undone using `REPLACE` calls, which I trust you don't need help with. The original `decodeValue` subroutine restores only double-quotes and spaces, leaving single-quotes as `&#39;`, so I don't know whether you would want to replicate that behaviour